# How to turn a if-statment into bitwise operations without if-statment

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have this task:

The three planes X=0, Y=0, and Z=0 divide the 3D space into 8 octant domains. Given an
array of 3D points, the following function counts the number of points belonging to each
octant. Write a version of that function which doesn’t use either if-statements or the if operator.

```c
typedef float pnt[3];
void count(pnt const * pnts, const int n, unsigned cnt[8]) {
 
  for(int i=0; i<8; ++i)
    cnt[i] = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    if(pnts[i][0]>=0.0f && pnts[i][1]>=0.0f && pnts[i][2]>=0.0f ) ++cnt[7]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]>=0.0f && pnts[i][1]>=0.0f && pnts[i][2]< 0.0f ) ++cnt[3]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]>=0.0f && pnts[i][1]< 0.0f && pnts[i][2]>=0.0f ) ++cnt[5]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]>=0.0f && pnts[i][1]< 0.0f && pnts[i][2]< 0.0f ) ++cnt[1]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]< 0.0f && pnts[i][1]>=0.0f && pnts[i][2]>=0.0f ) ++cnt[6]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]< 0.0f && pnts[i][1]>=0.0f && pnts[i][2]< 0.0f ) ++cnt[2]; else
    if(pnts[i][0]< 0.0f && pnts[i][1]< 0.0f && pnts[i][2]>=0.0f ) ++cnt[4]; else
    ++cnt[0];
}
```

What is the best way of solving this?

Comment: _"I have this task:"_ - is this homework? Do you have any proposals or attempts started by yourself? [The following meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/4573247) (_"Providing an answer that doesn't help a student learn is not in the student's own best interest."_) have some nice guidelines on homework-ish questions, that aims to help the student learn as much as possible, whilst still allowing the community to support a student when their own attempts have run dry.

Comment: step 0: Pick one language

Comment: Hint: the result of a boolean expression can be interpreted as a 0/1 integer

Comment: instead `if (a>0) c++;` you can write `c += a>0;` but I'm not sure such approach leads to the "expected" solution to your task.

Comment: i dont know why ppl always focus on "the best". Do you have any solution? As long as you have nothing anything **is** the best

Comment: Is the idea really to apply bitwise operations to floats? That is what i understand, but it horrifies me. If that is, please describe your knowledge of the internal format of the floats you are allowed to assume. If you cannot answer this, then finding this out is the first thing you need to do for your assignment and for this question, which can otherwise not be answered.

Comment: You can always use the **Conditional Operator** .

Comment: `pnts[i][0] >= 0`, `pnts[i][1] >= 0`, and `pnts[i][2] >= 0` each produce a value of 0 or 1. You can linearly combine them using power-of-2 multipliers 1, 2 and 4 to produce a value in the range 0 to 7 indicating the quadrant.

Comment: @alex I guess that is what OP means with "if operator", it is excluded

Answer (score 3):

First each condition sets bit, and resulting bitfield is the index:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    unsigned index = 
        ((pnts[i][0] >= 0.0f) << 0) |
        ((pnts[i][1] >= 0.0f) << 1) |
        ((pnts[i][2] >= 0.0f) << 2);
    ++cnt[index];
}
```

This approach takes advantage of the fact that `>=` operator returns either `0` or `1`, which is then shifted to correct position.